# Angular 2- Error Cannot assign to a reference or variable

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel, ng-template

I am using Angular 2. I have 2 nested `ng-template` as below:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-support [ngForOf]="support">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="form-group form-float">
          <div class="form-line focused">
             <select [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="support.option" class="form-control">
                 <option value="1">1</option>
                 <option value="2">2</option>
                 <option value="3">3</option>
                 <option value="4">4</option>                                   
             </select>
             <label class="form-label">Option</label>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <ng-template ngFor let-op3 [ngForOf]="support.option3">
          <select [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="op3" class="form-control">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
          <label class="form-label">Option3</label>
       </ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

It works fine without the inner `ng-template`. With having the inner loop it throws the following error:

> core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot assign
>   to a reference or variable! Error: Cannot assign to a reference or
>   variable!

Here is the Support model:

```
{
"support": [
      {
        "option": "string",
        "option2": "string",
        "option3": ["string"]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use `ng-container` instead of `ng-template` to bind the `ngFor` directive. It will reduce the complexity of the pseude-code in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it! I had to change the inner binding to:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-op3 [ngForOf]="support.option3" let-op3Index="index2">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="form-group form-float">
             <div class="form-line focused">
                <select [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="op3[index2]" class="form-control">
                    <option value="xxx">xxx</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
              <label class="form-label">Option3</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error I met caused by my ng-template name
is the same with another ngModel parameter name.

```
<ng-template #test></ng-template>
<xx [(ngModel)]="test">
```

changing the template name works